# Strange SMS received on Android phone. Is this an exploit? Should I be concerned?

Tags: android

I am using an Android phone. I received an SMS from an unknown number today which had the following content:

```
#Gege%wghatdanaipop%^
*%95bornioke:&67;
///Hackmaster&67;-&67"
//Fregbugg190&@"67"@/ ;
 :;whatsappash/@"hack:///
<#instruct~bug*omeg!#%
#%uthumb:"
?nail:/-67;bug__gegr>
;thumbnail\~>%
/:call log;&"#%
#05:32;&mondaybug&"
/:thumbnail;again|\]
#10:08;mondaybug &"
/:@thumbnail!\*;
#02:06;&fridaybug&"
/:#%allelements((crashed?)
;)&@(
-/7890@"$>
;:/endallow/thumbnails)&@"
/),.bugedit&@"
\{{Elementscrashed}}#%
"(<altedit)>•)*"
:@endbug:;"
:/&@"all*^^#
/)@allcrack<~|_]}}
-//userdemoadd:)&@"
~<>%^
\{{ensall<>%^*
```

> ([gist version](https://gist.github.com/vik-y/2cdb1160027571ff816a))

It looks very weird. Any idea what it is? I am curious as I was afraid that it can lead to some bug in applications which read SMS? Is it possible?

Comment: It's probably one of your friends trolling you using a free texting app.. This looks completely fake. Like a text message could activate '///Hackmaster' lol. as if it's running a program that's already on your phone. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Did you post this? http://pastebin.com/NdJSfWfZ

Comment: I also thought it was a troll. Better safe than be sorry. It's very much possible that a well framed text message can crash a program, so I was curious.

Comment: This is true. Your concern is understandable. If you're truly concerned about it, I can further assist you in possibly discovering if anything could happen. You can contact me through skype - l1thal (black and white angel pic). I'll be able to chat easier and collect more details to help myself understand if there is a greater risk. but from the looks of it you're fine. up to you.

Comment: I just posted it on gist.github.. Nowhere else

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the contents in this SMS Message, looking at lines as:

```
///Hackmaster&67;-&67"
//Fregbugg190&@"67"@/ ;
```

You'll notice these are all random characters, especially this Hackmaster line, which of course paired with these random characters could arouse suspicion around non-tech savvy people.

As mentioned in a comment before by others, it indeed looks like someone trying to troll/prank you, your suspicion isn't a bad thing however, referring back to the case of the [Apple iMessage Glitch](http://www.express.co.uk/life-style/science-technology/580211/iPhone-Messages-iMessage-Bug-Text-Reboot-Crash).

Long story short, I shouldn't worry too much about this specific text ;)

Comment: Random characters? You mean the binary payload.